# Print log in released runtime

Tags: vb.net, debugging, exception, logging

When running a program in VS debug mode, I use the Debug.Print and watch the Immidiate Window. I'm sure there are more advanced ways to debug, but I haven't learned so far.

But I would like to know how is the best way to track both log of exceptions as well as in-code specific method print-outs (like Debug.Print), during "released" runtime; outside VS.

I would like for two purpose:

1. Write to log text-file
2. Write to UI window, like a rich-textbox.

Is this a case I should use Console.Writline?  I have never used that, so if you could briefly explain if this is the right tool for what I want to accomplish, or what other ways I should consider.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest looking at [log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) rather than using Writeline. It is more robust, comprehensive, easy to use and configurable.

There an introduction [here](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2007/04/log4net-net-logging-tool.html).

One of the major benefits of using a logging tool like log4Net is the ability to turn on (verbose) logging at runtime.

Comment: Is this a simple library I can include?  Does it need much configuration? Since the purpose I listed are quite modest features, I don't want to spend time learning a complicated tool to accomplish that. But if it's plug-n-play it could be good.

Comment: @bretddog: it's only slightly more complicated then using writeline. There is a config file, but it is fairly simple. Consider it investing in your own skillset.

Comment: Of course. :) It's just as a newbie, there are no lack of things to learn, so a day spent on overkill is much a day wasted, postponing more essential stuff. Sure I could write some simple Log class with shared methods that will write to file etc, I just thought it may be some built in quick-to-use solutions already in .NET, for such purpose. So I did not need to add anything extra for this feature.